# How to Show Certifications in Your Resume that is Partially Fulfilled

Tags: resume, certification

I am IT auditor and will be soon taking my certification exam - CISA from ISACA. Certification requirements call for passing a rigorous exam as well as a certain number of years of related job experience working in IT Audit / Security / Compliance.

I have not fulfilled the work experience yet, and require 2 additional years working. Although I don't have the certification yet, I feel showing I have achieved tangible results in becoming certified show dedication to the audit profession.

**If I were to pass the exam, how can show this in my resume without misleading employers?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you pass, you are absolutely entitled to write in your CV that you have passed the CISA examination and are earning your 2 further years for the CISA title.

Even in ISACA, this status is known as exam-passers.

HR and recruiters in this market understand exactly what this means.

(My experience in this space comes from 4 years as President of ISACA, Scotland Chapter, and many more years on the committee, and working with companies, recruiters, headhunters, HR reps etc...)

Oh, and best of luck with the exam!