# How to structure a resume to show a completed professional examination?

Tags: resume, certification

This is related to [my question that I asked here.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67773/how-to-show-certifications-in-your-resume-that-is-partially-fulfilled) Now that I have the status of CISA exam passer (See answer from Rory in link),

> **Where can I best present this achievement in my resume?**

I am thinking of two places:

1. As an addendum to my current job in the Work History section
2. Within the professional certifications and honors section

While I gained the experience to pass this exam mainly from my work, its not strictly a function of my job per se.

This achievement fits well in the professional certifications section, but **I have not actually achieved the CISA certification yet**. In order to apply for certification, I still need about 2 years of work experience. Hence this information could be misleading if present here.

Adding my status as a CISA exam passer, given the difficulty of the exam, should distinguish myself from other candidates in seeking a job in the IT Security / Audit profession. It speaks to my dedication.

Comment: Education and certifications section, just say you have passed the exam. Anyone who knows what it is will understand that status; the rest either will ask or not care.

Answer (score 3):

Similar situation like you, I have given so many competitive examination during my Post Graduation and got ranked also in some of the examinations.

So I thought of mentioning that achievement in my resume during my campus interview. So I asked my professor "**Should I mentioned that also in my resume? Will it help me?**"

The answer I was given was

> "You can add the section in your resume as **Achivements** and add
>   your additional activity there. But make sure that you mention only
>   few things there and that also in proper order, it means higher
>   achievement first and then so on"

I updated my resume as advice. And trust me it really worked. So its nothing wrong in mentioning achievements in resume. But make sure your resume length should not be affected due to this.